# Where con un tipo de datos CLOB en SqlDeveloper

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

¿Cómo puedo realizar el siguiente where en sqlDeveloper?

SELECT tal tal tal
WHERE *table.HASH* = *'hashString'*

Dónde *table.HASH* es un campo de tipo CLOB, y *hasString* es un string.

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a mi me funciono esto

```
select tal, tal... 
   from table.HASH
 where dbms_lob.instr(laCOLUMNATal,'hashString') > 0;
```

prueba, [Aca otras instrucciones que pueden ayudar](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_lob.htm#i998315)